# Disable install of VS Code server

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

I use my VS Code remote - SSH extension to jump between a lot my customers servers, and would actually like not install the VS Code server on every server that I use.

Is there a way not to install the VS Code server, when you use the Remote - SSH extension, or is there maybe even another extension I should use instead?

Comment: Check out the diagram yourself, https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview It is impossible to use VS Code Remote Development without VS Code Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it but not using the official remote - SSH, but the extension SSH FS, which is a little more combersome as it can see you'r "normal" ssh config, but i works.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Kelvin.vscode-sshfs

Answer (score 0):

To fix this on your own (without using the script mentioned above), you could simply log into each of the linux. cs servers (using SSH), then the command pkill -u  node , which will stop any running vscode-server processes